# Should I @Deprecate a Superclass Method?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding, deprecated

Let's say I'm extending `JFileChooser` and making an easy-to-use version, which I'm calling `SimpleFileChooser`.

It is structured such that it can either be `DIALOG_TYPE_OPEN` or `DIALOG_TYPE_SAVE` — hence, `JFileChooser`'s `showOpenDialog()` and `showSaveDialog()` methods are superfluous. I replace them with a method called `showDialog()` which returns a boolean, but this is where I find myself in a dilemma:

> Should I override the open/save methods and add `@Deprecated` tags to
>   them so that the API user knows they've been superseded? Would that
>   violate the annotation's [original purpose](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html#what)?
>
> Or would a notice in the documentation be enough? If so, where should
>   this notice be placed: in the class summary or above the overridden
>   methods? Should I even override the methods in the first place?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do what makes sense in your design, instead of striving for some hypothethical ideal of ontological purity. I'd use the `@Deprecated` because it clearly communicates "you're not supposed to use this method" and makes it a compiler warning.

Comment: That said, this is either not constructive (since there's a case to be made for both variants without much in terms of objective reasons to do one or the other), or at least off topic for SO. ([programmers.se] *maybe*.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are actually building a [facade](/questions/tagged/facade), a simplified version of already existing API. Thus instead of inheritance you should use composition. Hide the original `JFileChooser` inside your new class and provide simpler API.

As a last resort you can provide `public JFileChooser getRaw()` method to access wrapped object if some other code needs it.

Comment: I agree. Instance of his class will be instance of `JFileChooser` so they should be able to replace them, so the methods should work and not just be "deprecated". If he wants some of the JFileChooser functionality, he can built a wrapper around a JFileChooser and chose its API.

Answer (score 1):

@Deprecated means you should not use that particular class or method anymore as it will be removed in the future. That annotation is designed for that.
So to answer shortly, if you dont want API users to use the method anymore you should use @Deprecated. Because else you will end up with users that still use methods/classes that you remove in future builds and their projects will be broken when they update.